# How do I rewrite this MySQL query so it doesn't throw this error: You can't specify target table 'crawlLog' for update in FROM clause?

Tags: mysql, logging, join, mysql-error-1093

I'm trying to get an id from a companies table where the id is not yet in the crawlLog table.  Then I need to insert that companyId into the crawlLog table.

I need to do this in one call so that parallel crawlers don't pull the same url after some other crawler has selected a url, but hasn't inserted it into the crawl log yet.  I don't want to lock tables because of other problems that generates.

I get this error from both queries below:

```
You can't specify target table 'crawlLog' for update in FROM clause
```

Here are two queries i've tried to do the same thing.

```
INSERT INTO crawlLog (companyId, timeStartCrawling)
VALUES
(
    (
        SELECT companies.id FROM companies
        LEFT OUTER JOIN crawlLog
        ON companies.id = crawlLog.companyId
        WHERE crawlLog.companyId IS NULL
        LIMIT 1
    ),
    now()
)
```

I've also tried this, but get the same error:

```
INSERT INTO crawlLog (companyId, timeStartCrawling)
VALUES
(
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM companies
        WHERE id NOT IN
        (
            SELECT companyId
            FROM crawlLog
        )
        LIMIT 1
    ),
    now()
)
```

Comment: This could only be done reliably with a transaction and some locking. If you're on InnoDB, at least it'd only be a row-level lock and not a whole table lock.

Comment: Did you try to set an alias for the inner crawlLog?

Comment: @Tocco - you are the man!!!  That did it. This is a great trick.

Comment: Hey .. mark this as a great comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works and seems like the simplest solution:

Using the simpler of the two statements in my question, I created an alias for the inner crawlLog table as suggested by @Tocco in the comments, and then removed the necessary encapsulation in VALUES().

```
INSERT INTO crawlLog (companyId, timeStartCrawling)
SELECT id, now()
FROM companies
WHERE id NOT IN
(
    SELECT companyId
    FROM crawlLog AS crawlLogAlias
)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a problem or not, but putting a SELECT inside of VALUES seems odd (unnecessary).

Answer (score 3):

Why use a Subselect? INSERT INTO ... SELECT exists:

```
INSERT INTO crawlLog (companyId, timeStartCrawling)
SELECT companies.id, NOW()
FROM companies
LEFT OUTER JOIN crawlLog
ON companies.id = crawlLog.companyId
WHERE crawlLog.companyId IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

And that way it should not complain about using a table both in the INSERT and SELECT part

Answer (score 1):

[You can't update rows which you are querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007489/mysql-you-cant-specify-target-table-tasks-for-update-in-from-clause). There is a way to force MySQL to use a temporary table implicitly:

```
INSERT INTO crawlLog (companyId, timeStartCrawling)
VALUES
(
    SELECT id, when FROM
    (
    SELECT companies.id AS id, now() AS when FROM companies
    LEFT OUTER JOIN crawlLog
    ON companies.id = crawlLog.companyId
    WHERE crawlLog.companyId IS NULL
    LIMIT 1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the select into a temp table, then insert selecting from the temp table.  You can't insert into a table and select from it in the same statement, so use a temp table and two statements.