# You can't specify target table 'barang' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-error-1093

I have problem updating column `jml_tersedia` from table `barang`. The value should be: `barang.jml_tersedia = pembelian.jml_beli - penjualan.jml_jual`.

Here is my code:

```
update barang set jml_tersedia =
(
  ( select ifnull(sum(jml_beli), 0) 
    from pembelian 
    where pembelian.id_barang = (select id_barang 
                                 from barang 
                                 where nama_barang = 'folio')
  ) - 
  ( select ifnull(sum(jml_jual), 0) 
    from penjualan 
    where penjualan.id_barang = (select id_barang 
                                 from barang 
                                 where nama_barang = 'folio')
  ) 
)
where barang.nama_barang = 'folio';
```

It gave me `You can't specify target table 'barang' for update in FROM clause`. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL won't let you modify the same table that you're selecting from, but it does let you specify multiple tables in the `UPDATE` clause.

I've rephrased your `UPDATE` query to use `LEFT JOIN`'s instead of nested sub-`SELECT`'s.

Since I am not completely sure this query will do exactly what you need, you should first verify that you will get the desired updated value for `barang.jml_tersedia`.  Here it is, re-phrased as a `SELECT` query:

**Verify**:

```
SELECT
    (
        IFNULL(SUM(pb.jml_beli), 0) -
        IFNULL(SUM(pj.jml_jual), 0)
    ) AS new_jml_tersedia
FROM
    barang ba
    LEFT JOIN pembelian pb ON (ba.id_barang = pb.id_barang)
    LEFT JOIN penjualan pj ON (ba.id_barang = pj.id_barang)
WHERE
    ba.nama_barang = 'folio';
```

Once you're sure that it returns the correct update value, then you can run it, as such:

**Update**:

```
UPDATE
    barang ba
    LEFT JOIN pembelian pb ON (ba.id_barang = pb.id_barang)
    LEFT JOIN penjualan pj ON (ba.id_barang = pj.id_barang)
SET
    ba.jml_tersedia = (
        IFNULL(SUM(pb.jml_beli), 0) -
        IFNULL(SUM(pj.jml_jual), 0)
    );
WHERE
    ba.nama_barang = 'folio';
```

And, if this answer doesn't work out for you, then you could also look at these [excellent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498/114359) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6007513/114359) for alternate solutions.

Finally, you can consult MySQL's documentation to learn more about [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Comment: Thanks! It works just as I need it! I just need to edit the SET block to be >`ba.jml_tersedia = (
        select 
 (
 IFNULL(SUM(pb.jml_beli), 0) -
        IFNULL(SUM(pj.jml_jual), 0)
 )`